# Select specific rows based on date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to filter some rows from a dataframe based on a column with dates in datetime64[ns] format.

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('jeopardy.csv')
data.head(2)
```

| Show Number | Air Date | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | HISTORY | 200.0 |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | ESPN's TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES | 200.0 |

I just want to select the right rows based on the Air Date column. I have replaced this column with datetime64[ns] format. I write the appropriate conditions, but Google Colaboratory returns nothing to me, and I know that there are dates that meet the condition I wrote. I typed 2 version of this condition. What is wrong?

```
data['Air Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Air Date'])
data[data['Air Date'] > pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01')]
data[data['Air Date'] > ('2000-01-01')]
```

Comment: Both options works for me -

Comment: Both options work but do not change `data` in-place. Do you need to use `data = data[data['Air Date'] > pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01')]` ?